# Character doesn't move exact units with IEnumerator

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game like subway surfers. I have 3lanes in which the player can move.
The problem is when i press the move controls, the character moves a little more than 1 unit,  if i move from -1 to 0, my character will be in 0.02 or something like that. 
So after clicking movement controls A and D for 10-15times, my character is not in the lane , and goes   X=1.2, 0.3, -0.8 etc........
This problem is also with jump controls.
How to fix this ....
I am very beginner at unity. Just started during these days.
Please help me.
my coding is

```
 private string lanechange = "n";
    private string jumpcontrol = "n";


    void Start()
    {
         GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 3);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if((Input.GetKey("a")) && (lanechange=="n") && (transform.position.x>-.9f)  )
    {
          GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(-4, 0, 3);
        lanechange = "y";
        StartCoroutine (stoplanechange());

        }

      if((Input.GetKey("d")) && (lanechange=="n") && (transform.position.x<.9f) )
    {
          GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(4, 0, 3);
        lanechange = "y";
        StartCoroutine (stoplanechange());

        }

        if ((Input.GetKey("space")) && (jumpcontrol == "n") )
          {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 2, 3);
            jumpcontrol = "y";
            StartCoroutine(stopjump());
        }

    }

    IEnumerator stopjump()
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, -2, 3);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 3);
        jumpcontrol = "n";

    }

    IEnumerator stoplanechange()

    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);


         GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 3);



        lanechange = "n";
        Debug.Log(GetComponent<Transform>().position);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rigidbody and the velocity to make it move, you are using the physics system to make your character move. The Physics system has a different timestep, which is linked to the `FixedUpdate()` function, not to Update.

But input is always bound to `Update()`, which is synchronous to the graphics and keyboard input.

So timing a move like that will always be off a little, even depending on graphics framerate.

I suggest that you put in place some logic what makes your character lock into the lane you are closest to. The move-key makes it move roughly, at least half the lane-width, then the back-to-center takes over and centers him.

Comment: yes.. i changed the mechanism of this movement. Thanks.